# How to add unselectable instruction text to the QComboBox

Tags: qt

I have a QComboBox with the items.

I want to put some instruction as top item in my combo box such as "Select number..". It shouldn't be selected too.

is there anyway to do it in QComboBox widget?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initially put an instruction item as a regular item and remove it from the combo box when it is clicked at the first time. This signal signal 
should do the job

```
void highlighted(int index);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the item unselectable via the list model.  Something like:

```
comboBox->model()->itemData(0)->setEnabled(false)
```

But you might need a cast in there, not sure: I use PySide so I don't :-)

Comment: Thank you. It should be                                    comboBox->model()->itemData(0)->setEnabled(false)

Comment: Oh yeah - sorry - fixed now.